# To check if specific value is present in a variable

Tags: vba

In my code, I need to detect if Evenments is present in the variable. I try to make it in the if statements but it does not work. Any ideas thanks, below is my code :
My variable name is : Planning_CAMBON19_VM_Evenements_T3_2020.xlsx

```
 Dim strPath As String


strPath = nomfichier_Boutique
'MsgBox (strPath)
Debug.Print strPath

Dim strFilee As String
strFilee = Right(strPath, Len(strPath) - InStrRev(strPath, "\"))

MsgBox (strFilee)

If strFilee = "Evenements" Then

MsgBox "vALID"

Else

MsgBox "iNVALID"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

`InStr` is what you're looking for to check if one string is present inside another string.

```
If InStr(strFilee, "Evenements") Then
```